# Use Realm with Collection View Data Source Best Practise

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm

I'll make it short as possible.

I have an API request that I fetch data from (i.e. Parse).

When I'm getting the results I'm writing it to Realm and then adding them to a `UICollectionView`'s data source.

There are requests that take a bit more time, which run asynchronous. I'm getting the needed results after the data source and collection view was already reloaded.

I'm writing the needed update from the results to my Realm database.

I have read that it's possible to use Realm's [`Results`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html). But I honestly didn't understood it. I guess there is a dynamic and safe way working with collection views and Realm. Here is my approach for now.

This is how I populate the collection view's data source at the moment:

#### Declaration

```
var dataSource = [Realm_item]()
```

where `Realm_item` is a Realm `Object` type.

#### Looping and Writing

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for nowResult in FetchedResultsFromAPI
    {
        let item = Realm_item()
        item.item_Title = nowResult["Title"] as! String
        item.item_Price = nowResult["Price"] as! String
        // Example - Will write it later after the collectionView Done - Async request
        GetFileFromImageAndThanWriteRealm(x.image) 
        // Example - Will write it later after the collectionView Done - Async request
        dataSource.append(item)
    }

   //After finish running over the results *Before writing the image data*
    try! self.realm.write {
        self.realm.add(self.dataSource)
    }
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

After I write the image to Realm to an already created "object". Will the same Realm Object (with the same primary key) automatically update over in the data source?

What is the right way to update the object from the data source after I wrote the update to same object from the Realm DB?

#### Update

#### Model class

```
class Realm_item: Object {
   dynamic var item_ID : String!
    dynamic var item_Title : String!
    dynamic var item_Price : String!
    dynamic var imgPath : String?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "item_ID"
    }
}
```

First I'm checking whether the "object id" exists in the Realm. If it does, I fetch the object from Realm and append it to the data source. If it doesn't exist, I create a new Realm object, write it and than appending it.

#### Fetching the data from Parse

This happens in the `viewDidLoad` method and prepares the data source:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Realm_item")
query.limit = 100
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (respond, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
        for x in respond!
        {            
            if let FetchedItem =  self.realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Realm_item.self,  key: x.objectId!)
            {
                self.dataSource.append(FetchedItem)        
            }
            else
            {
                let item = Realm_item()
                item.item_ID = x.objectId
                item.item_Title = x["Title"] as! String
                item.item_Price = x["Price"] as! String
                let file = x["Images"] as! PFFile
                RealmHelper().getAndSaveImageFromPFFile(file, named: x.objectId!)
                self.dataSource.append(item)
            }
        }

        try! self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add(self.dataSource)
        }

        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
        print(respond?.count)
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a few questions and problems here, so I'll do my best.

I suggest you use the Results type as your data source, something like:

`var dataSource: Results<Realm_item>?`

Then, in your `viewDidLoad()`:

`dataSource = realm.objects(Realm_item)`.

Be sure to use the relevant error checking before using dataSource. We use an optional `Results<Realm_item>` because the Realm object you're using it from needs to be initialised first. I.e., you'll get something like `"Instance member * cannot be used on type *"` if you try declaring the results like `let dataSource = realm.objects(Realm_item)`.

---

The [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) (a very well-written and useful reference to have when you're using Realm as beginner like myself), has this to say about Results...

> Results are live, auto-updating views into the underlying data, which means results never have to be re-fetched. Modifying objects that affect the query will be reflected in the results immediately.

Your mileage may vary depending on how you have everything set up. You could try posting your Realm models and Parse-related code for review and comment.

Your last question:

> What is the right way to update the "object" from the Data Source after i wrote the update to same object from the Realm DB?

I gather you're asking the best way to update your UI (CollectionView) when the underlying data has been updated? If so...

> You can subscribe to [Realm notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) to know when Realm data is updated, indicating when your app’s UI should be refreshed for example, without having to re-fetch your Results.

Comment: First of all case, Thank you! I'll update my code above to provide more information about it.

Comment: I have updated the code :). A few question - 1) for the "Results" type array, Can i set up specific query as well? for example, like i did above? crate the "Results" array by appending objects and not just by query? 2) If i register to Realm notification, How can i update the specific item at the data Source as well? Thank you!